# How to bind drop down field value in another input field using meanjs?

Tags: html, angularjs, meanjs

- How to bind drop down field value in another input field using meanjs.
- Hi all Please look at this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/vokoid1DTQZnYyAjaNmJ?p=preview) i have created,
- What I exactly looking is first we select `school` in plunker then we select `school section`, then there is a one `input filed` is available so what i need is `section` need to `bind` in that `input text field`...
- **for example** :- if we select `7A (or) 8A` in `section dropdown`, this `section value` needs to `bind` that `input field`, now it's showing error like '[object Object]'...so how to do this.

**My Html:-**

```
     <div>
  <label>1. Without array value</label>
  <select ng-model="question"  ng-options="item.title for item in questions">
  </select>
  </div>

  <div style="margin-top: 11px;">
  <label>2. With comments array value</label>
  <select style="margin-left: 20px;" ng-model="class"  ng-options="item.commentText  for item in question.comments">
  </select>
  {{class.commentText}}
  </div>

  <div>
    <input type="text"  ng-model="newclass"  ng-bind="newclass=class"/>
  </div>
```

**Input Field:-**

```
    <div>
    <input type="text"  ng-model="newclass"  ng-bind="newclass=class"/>
  </div>
```

**My Data** :-

```
    $scope.questions = [
{
"_id": "59df6c37b6748bc809050699",
"user": {
"_id": "59df6a76b6748bc809050697",
"profileImageURL": "modules/users/client/img/profile/default.png"
},
"__v": 1,
"openeyers": [],
"openeyes": 0,
"upvoters": [],
"upvotes": 0,
"isLiked": false,
"users": [],
"comments": [
{
"created": 1507897712831,
"email": "ms@e21designs.com",
"name": "Maniselvam selvam",
"link": "https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/0B5c-p1bvkfS9REJHMGhMY1BTV1k",
"commentText": "7A"
}
],
"questionid": "",
"title": "Silver jublie",
"created": "2017-10-12T13:20:55.383Z"
},
{
"_id": "59df6c37b6748bc809050699",
"user": {
"_id": "59df6a76b6748bc809050697",
"displayName": "Maniselvam selvam",
"dob": "1991-05-10T07:00:00.000Z",
"profileImageURL": "modules/users/client/img/profile/default.png"
},
"__v": 1,
"openeyers": [],
"users": [],
"comments": [
{
"created": 1507897712831,
"email": "ms@e21designs.com",
"name": "Maniselvam selvam",
"link": "https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/0B5c-p1bvkfS9REJHMGhMY1BTV1k",
"commentText": "8A"
}
],
"questionid": "",
"title": "Public School",
"created": "2017-10-12T13:20:55.383Z"
}
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to do that first

Simple set input `ng-model` to `class.commentText`  something like

```
<input type="text"  ng-model="class.commentText"  />
```

But this will result in change in select option if you change input

Second way

asssign value to `newClass` on select value change

```
 <select style="margin-left: 20px;" ng-model="class" ng-change="newClass=class.commentText"  ng-options="item.commentText  for item in question.comments">
  </select>

<input type="text"  ng-model="newClass"  />
```

[Working demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/PCVJWlT4I9RzkMhBCN2S?p=preview)

Comment: And one more thing please look at this plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/OHJ4BwQTsvqeJymzNWKq?p=preview i have added one more `input filed` also and how can i fetch this section `link` into another input filed... for example:- if we selected `7A` in section this particular link needs to fetch in another input field ...please help us thanks....

Comment: Jitender any idea? how can do this in second method bcoz first method is fine in plunker but in project , look at updated plunker :- http://plnkr.co/edit/6AdbGl2DAjSPSiJtUeCz?p=preview i am exactly looking same solution using in second method please help us

Comment: set other input model `class.link` like `ng-model="class.link"`

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/r7qAVcTzpoceTstImMeR?p=preview yes that i know , but I am looking the solution which you have update in second way like that... `<input type="text"  ng-model="newClass"  />`

Comment: please update this plunker as well :- http://plnkr.co/edit/y8eAAuvVytdezbwEMpr6?p=preview

Comment: input model is must should different and section model also different

Comment: thanks for your answer it's working perfectly but only one bug is there if used school ` ng-options="item.title for item in questions"` like this it's saved as a id not like name 'vellamal (or) public school` , and then if used school ` ng-options="item.title as item.title for item in questions"` it's saved as name like 'vellamal' but section dropdown and link is not working is there any solution.....?

Comment: Hi I am looking for same related answer so please check this and update thanks  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47506303/how-to-get-the-value-like-first-drop-down-value-related-to-another-drop-down-val